# How to use logical operator (!) with magrittr in R

Tags: r, magrittr

I am taking a list of values and trying to find those that are not NA using magrittr.  Here is a simple example:

```
data.frame(data = c(1:2, NA, 4:5, NA, 7)) %>% is.na
```

which yields the correct result:

```
      data
[1,] FALSE
[2,] FALSE
[3,]  TRUE
[4,] FALSE
[5,] FALSE
[6,]  TRUE
[7,] FALSE
```

When I put the not operator `!` in front of `is.na`, I get an error:

```
data.frame(data = c(1:2, NA, 4:5, NA, 7)) %>% !is.na
```

gives me

`Error in FUN(left, right) : operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types`

After many trials, I stumbled upon this, which works:

```
 data.frame(data = c(1:2, NA, 4:5, NA, 7)) %>% is.na %>% !.

      data
[1,]  TRUE
[2,]  TRUE
[3,] FALSE
[4,]  TRUE
[5,]  TRUE
[6,] FALSE
[7,]  TRUE
```

My question is whether there is a different way to do this.  There are other alias options in the package but I don't see any examples of them.  One is "not".  Maybe I should be using that instead?

I realize that I have answered my question to some degree, but I would like to know if this can be done without having to resort to `%>% !.` at the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just move the negation to the "front". This is how you typically negate the `%in%` infix operatiuon

```
 !data.frame(data = c(1:2, NA, 4:5, NA, 7)) %>% is.na

      data
[1,]  TRUE
[2,]  TRUE
[3,] FALSE
[4,]  TRUE
[5,]  TRUE
[6,] FALSE
[7,]  TRUE
```

Comment: Yup.  Shorter.  I like both answers, but this is the cleanest.

Comment: This works if negation is the last operation required in the chain.

Answer (score 8):

You can use backticks to pipe your result into the function underlying the operator:

```
> data.frame(data = c(1:2, NA, 4:5, NA, 7)) %>% is.na %>% `!`
      data
[1,]  TRUE
[2,]  TRUE
[3,] FALSE
[4,]  TRUE
[5,]  TRUE
[6,] FALSE
[7,]  TRUE
```

Alternatively use the `Negate` function:

```
> data.frame(data = c(1:2, NA, 4:5, NA, 7)) %>% Negate(is.na)()
      data
[1,]  TRUE
[2,]  TRUE
[3,] FALSE
[4,]  TRUE
[5,]  TRUE
[6,] FALSE
[7,]  TRUE
```

Comment: OK.  That makes sense.  That works and I also replaced `\`!`\` with `not` which also works.  And that explains the purpose of the alias.

Comment: Yes `not` is defined as `function (x)  .Primitive("!")` which is the same as calling the function underlying the `!` operator.

Comment: I also considered adding ...not as an alias to make it really expressive ;)

Comment: I like this answer because it both leaves the operator in the location where you'd "expect" to read it and because it shows how to separate an operator from the `magrittr` pipe operators.

Comment: Both of these answers are good.  I would accept both if I could.

Answer (score 5):

Or even

```
data.frame(data = c(1:2, NA, 4:5, NA, 7)) %>% 
  is.na %>% 
 `n'est pas`
```