# Assign unique ID based on values in EITHER of two columns

Tags: r, dplyr

**This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39650511/r-group-by-variable-and-then-assign-a-unique-id).** Please read questions entirely before labeling duplicates.

I have a data.frame like so:

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble(
  color = c("blue", "blue", "red", "green", "purple"),
  shape = c("triangle", "square", "circle", "hexagon", "hexagon")
)

  color  shape   
  <chr>  <chr>   
1 blue   triangle
2 blue   square  
3 red    circle  
4 green  hexagon 
5 purple hexagon
```

I'd like to add a `group_id` column like this:

```
  color  shape    group_id
  <chr>  <chr>       <dbl>
1 blue   triangle        1
2 blue   square          1
3 red    circle          2
4 green  hexagon         3
5 purple hexagon         3
```

The difficulty is that I want to group by unique values of `color` *or* `shape`. I suspect the solution might be to use list-columns, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: Thanks, @akrun. Your answer is very helpful. I really thought other users would have high enough reading comprehension to recognize that this is a different issue than the basic group_by issue linked to in the duplicate report.

Comment: Making sure people understand exactly what you're asking is one reason why it's helpful to see what you've tried. That could show what your approach to the question is, even if your code doesn't work

Comment: Just as an aside, you can [@ notify gold badge holders](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) that unilaterally close questions as duplicates in the comments of the question. Unless they are following your question (unlikely), editing your question will not notify them. I agree with you that this is not a duplicate of the target, so I voted to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `duplicated` in `base R`

```
df1$group_id <- cumsum(!Reduce(`|`, lapply(df1, duplicated)))
```

-output

```
df1
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#  color  shape    group_id
#  <chr>  <chr>       <int>
#1 blue   triangle        1
#2 blue   square          1
#3 red    circle          2
#4 green  hexagon         3
#5 purple hexagon         3
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(group_id = map(.,  duplicated) %>%
                         reduce(`|`) %>%
                         `!` %>% 
                       cumsum)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(color = c("blue", "blue", "red", "green", "purple"
), shape = c("triangle", "square", "circle", "hexagon", "hexagon"
)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: FYI look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345244/how-to-use-logical-operator-with-magrittr-in-r) for further discussion of negation `!` with the pipe `%>%`